# Does a string use a list to store char's?

Tags: string, list, data-structures

Curious if a string data type uses a list to store its characters? And if so, what is the list implementation type?

Other than being immutable, a String has elements and index positions like a list so wondering if a String is actually a list data structure.

Comment: I believe that in many languages it is actually an *array* of characters

Answer (score 0):

In most modern programming languages, a string is a wrapper around an array. In .NET, for example, the backing store is an array of 16-bit integers, each of which holds a single UTF-16 code point. Whatever the backing store, member functions provide indexing and such.

In C, there isn't even a string type. What we call strings are really just arrays of characters. There are certain rules for the format of those arrays (like a null byte, `\0`, terminates the string), and "string functions" that operate on those arrays as though they are strings.

There are string handling libraries that use [ropes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)) to more efficiently manipulate long strings.

Note also that not all languages specify that strings are immutable. In some languages, you can modify individual characters within the string, and do some other things without actually creating a new string object.

Comment: Arrays seem like a logical fit for String implementation...Does that mean behind the scenes, when you declare a String ie Java, it assigns creates an array of String length and populates the elements with each character?

In the few languages I know, Strings are immutable.

Comment: @chappie According to http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java#String, the Java `String` class allocates an array of `char` to hold the value.